# insert BigDecimal to database with vertx-jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, bigdecimal, vert.x

I am using the vertx-jdbc-client (http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/) for my database connection. This works fine for every data type except **BigDecimal**.

In my database the type is **decimal(13,2)**, in Java I am using a **BigDecimal** data type. I just want to read & update this column with the vertx-jdbc-client.

Unfortunately I get following exception:

```
    SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal type in JsonObject: class java.math.BigDecimal
    at io.vertx.core.json.Json.checkAndCopy(Json.java:215)
    at io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray.add(JsonArray.java:444)
```

Looking at io.vertx.core.json.Json.checkAndCopy tells me that BigDecimal is not supported by the framework:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static Object checkAndCopy(Object val, boolean copy) {
    if (val == null) {
      // OK
    } else if (val instanceof Number && !(val instanceof BigDecimal)) {
      // OK
    } else if (val instanceof Boolean) {
...
}
```

I googled a bit, but did not found an explanation why this not supported.

**Is there a solution for this?**

Following Versions are used:
(Java 8, Vertx 3.5.0, Postgres 9.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `BigDecimal` to `String` and then use the `CAST` function:

```
INSERT INTO test (i) VALUES (CAST('3.235' AS DECIMAL))
```

And to read it back:

```
SELECT CAST(i AS TEXT) from test
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working. One drawback is that the `@DataObject(generateConverter = true)` from Vert.x codegen cannot be used to because codegen ignores the BigDecimal type. Do you know a way to tell the converter to accept BigDecimal?

Comment: No you can't tell the convert to accept `BigDecimal`. But since the converter needs to be called from user code, you can add something for the `BigDecimal` field in the method where it's used.

Comment: Good, to know. I added it manually, but I would have preferred another solution. Thanks!